# NSInteger = NSInteger -1?

Tags: objective-c

I am trying to do a very simple thing but I can't figure out how;

```
NSInteger * a=10;
a=a-1;
NSlog(@"a=%d",a);
```

For some reason it's showing `a=6`.

How can it be?

Comment: Because you've declared a **pointer**?

Comment: small typos can have a big impact

Comment: This is one area of Objective-C/Cocoa that I've never really liked. A lack of decent namespacing and the merging of Cocoa classes, Cocoa types, Cocoa functions and Cocoa constants (integer constants AND string constants) into the one generic "NS"-prefixed mess. `NSType t = NSFunction([NSClass methodWithConstant:NSConstant | NSConstant2])`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your problem is that you've declared the variable `a` as a pointer.
Most Objective-C variables are pointers, but `NSInteger` is an exception, because it's just `typedef`'d to `int` or `long`.

Your code should look like this:

```
NSInteger a=10;
a=a-1;
NSlog(@"a=%d",a);
```

When you do math on a pointer, you are actually moving the location in memory it points to. For example if the size of an `NSInteger` is 4 (`sizeof(NSInteger) == 4`), moving it -1, or in other words, a one structure size back, the pointer gets decreased by 4.
This mechanique is heavily used in C when iterating arrays of structures, e.g.

```
CGPoint myPoints[4];
CGPoint* point = myPoints; //get the first point

for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
   CGPoint currentPoint = *point;
   point++; //moves to the next point, adding sizeof(CGPoint)
}
```

This is called pointer arithmetic and you can write it in different ways, e.g. `pointer + 1` but also `point[1]` or `1[point]` (the last two are actually equal to `*(pointer + 1)`).

Comment: There is quite a few structs as well, like `NSRect`, `NSPoint`, `CGRect`, `CGPoint`, `CGColor` (though commonly used as `CGColorRef` (a pointer to a struct)), etc.

Comment: You should explain why a pointer, which is also an integer, moves -4 when you do -1 :)

Comment: @Sulthan I updated my answer with a brief explanation of how *I think* it works…